# How to get client IP in Fiddler from machine that ran fiddlercap capture

Tags: localhost, client, ip-address, fiddler, clientip

I've searched and found a number of different resources which describe how to get the `client IP` address in `fiddler`.

```
public static BindUIColumn("ClientIP")
function CalcMethodColClientIP(oS: Session){
    if (null != oS.oRequest) return oS.oFlags["X-ClientIP"]; else return String.Empty; 
}
```

I believe `oSession.clientIP` should also work. First of all, all that gives me is 127.0.0.1. It doesn't tell me the IP address of the machine, just the localhost `loopback` IP address. I'm looking for the actual IP address of the machine.

My main objective is getting the client IP address in a `fiddlercap` capture that was run on another person's machine. This person sent me the fiddercap log, which I view with fiddler. I want to retrieve his machine's IP address with fiddler. How can I accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the FiddlerCap log will not provide this information by default. I'd considered adding a button to capture machine info (e.g. out of MSInfo32) automatically as a Session in the capture, but that was never implemented.

The `X-ClientIP` field only holds the IP address which the client used to talk to the proxy; in almost all cases, this is `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Woa! We got a celebrity in the house :) Is Google hiring? lol. Answer direct from the source here. Thank you so much for your help, as well as this too!. It's become the Kleenix or Xerox of HTTP Proxy debuggers. Again, very much appreciate your insight. If you do add this functionality, that would be great. Can you capture the machine's IP address with Fiddler itself, as opposed to FiddlerCap? I tried with Fiddler alone, no FiddlerCap, and still only got the localhost IP.

Comment: In Fiddler, you can type in QuickExec `about:network` to spew the network configuration to the LOG tab. Then type `log @Log.Save` and it'll store the LOG tab's text as a new Session in the Web Sessions list; that data will be stored when you save a SAZ file containing all sessions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Well, if it SharePoint Server you can get on the server, run
Get-SpServer | Select ID
```

Then use the following code in fiddler to see what SharePoint Server responded.  Just add the below code to the Main() function entry point. You will find this in Rules > Custom Rules > the CRTL F to find the Main() Function to add this code to. One you do it. You will have a EncodedServerId column that you will see the last half of your get-spserver ID that uniquely identifies your SharePoint Server. You get the id for every server in the farm and you will know regardless of load balancer which server sent the response.

```
 public static BindUIColumn("EncodedServerId",65,1)
    function CalcMachineId(oSession: Session){
        if (null != oSession.oResponse && oSession.oResponse.headers!= null) { 
            if (oSession.oResponse.headers.Exists("SPRequestGuid") || oSession.oResponse.headers.Exists("request-id")){
                if(oSession.oResponse.headers.Exists("SPRequestGuid")){
                    var requestGuid = Guid.Parse(oSession.oResponse.headers["SPRequestGuid"]);
                }
                else{
                    var requestGuid = Guid.Parse(oSession.oResponse.headers["request-id"]);
                }
                var bytes = requestGuid.ToByteArray();
                var partOne = parseInt(bytes[8]) << 12;
                var partTwo = parseInt(bytes[9]) << 4;
                var partThree = parseInt(bytes[10]) >> 4;
                var id = partOne + partTwo + partThree;
                return String.Format("{0}",id);
            }
            return String.Empty;
            }         return "None";   
    }
```